# Laplace transform of scaling function

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I'm currently doing a class in differential equations and the first subject is  laplace transforms - I'm struggling with this task however;

> Let $f$ be a continuous function with scaling symmetry given by $f(mt)=m^kf(t)$ for any $m>0$ Show that $(\mathcal{Lf})(s) = m^{-k-1}\frac{s}{m}(\mathcal{Lf})$

I don't see a way to apply the laplace transforms I know already - is there a certain theorem that simplifies this a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the Laplace transform,
$$
\mathcal L[f]\left(\frac{s}{m}\right)= \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st/m}dt = m\int_0^\infty f(m u) e^{-su}du = m^{k+1}\int_0^\infty f(u) e^{-su}du = m^{k+1}\mathcal{L}[f](s).
$$
Dividing through by $m^{k+1}$ gives
$$
\mathcal{L}[f](s) = m^{-k-1}\mathcal{L}[f]\left(\frac{s}{m}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I follow everything after the third ''=''. I'm a little confused by the notation: $\mathcal{L}[f]\frac{s}{m}$. What does this really mean - how does it become $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st/m} dt$? Specifically - where does the division by $m$ in the exponent come from?

Comment: @novo $f$ is a function, and $\mathcal{L}[f]$ is the Laplace transform of that function. $\mathcal{L}[f](s/m)$ is the evaluation of that Laplace transform at $s/m$. Since $\mathcal{L}[f](s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$, it follows that $\mathcal{L}[f](s/m) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st/m}dt$.